# when I upload multiple files with dropzone.js, don't know how to receive parameter with spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, dropzone.js

When I use `dropzone.js` to upload many files, the problem is appearing.

I need add more parameter to `POST` request, I have read the documentation on `dropzonejs.com` and wiki on `github.com`, parameter is added to request.

The problem is that the default parameter of file is `files[0]`,`files[1]` ...(I set the `paramName` option to `files`), but I can't receive `files` parameters with java spring mvc code.

This is my spring mvc controller code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/upload")
    public Map<String,Object> method(CaseInfo info,HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("files[]")MultipartFile[] files){
        ...
    }
```

This is my js core code:

```
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                    console.log("formData ->", formData);
                    var frm = $('#form');
                    var data = frm.serializeArray();
                    console.log('data ->', data);
                    for (var obj in data) {
                        formData.append(obj.name, obj.value);
                    }
                });
```

The controller just can't receive files parameter, and the name of others is `undefined`,

#### edited:

I changed the for-in to below, then the `undefined` problem solved.
But I don't know why...  somebody know?

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        var obj = data[i];
                        formData.append(obj.name,obj.value);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by overwriting the source js code.

```
Dropzone.prototype._getParamName = function(n) {
            if (typeof this.options.paramName === "function") {
                return this.options.paramName(n);
            } else {
//                return "" + this.options.paramName + (this.options.uploadMultiple ? "[" + n + "]" : "");
                return "" + this.options.paramName;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Understood this is an old question but I've had some success changing the "sending" option to "sendingmultiple" then passing a function that simply returns "files" to match up with the spring controller signature:

js

```
    sendingmultiple: function(files, xhr, formData) {
        // additional request paramter
        formData.append('media', JSON.stringify(media));
        for (const [key, value] of formData) {
            console.log('key: ' + key + ' value: ' + value);
        }
    },
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    paramName: function() { return "files"; }
```

java

```
    @PostMapping("/user/media/upload")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User uploadMedia(@RequestParam String media, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
```